# SQL having and max

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query:

```
SELECT P.lastname, P.firstname, MAX(MD.movie_id)
FROM Person AS P
INNER JOIN Movie_Directors AS MD ON P.person_id = MD.person_id
INNER JOIN Movie AS M ON M.movie_id = MD.movie_id
GROUP BY P.firstname, P.lastname, MD.movie_id
HAVING MAX(MD.movie_id);
```

I get this error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'

I need to get a SQL select for the next question, I don't understand the error can anyone help?

The query needs to display the director who has produced the most films so far [firstname, lastname].

Comment: 1. The `HAVING` clause requires a comparison, 2. `MAX` will return the highest ID movie every director has, not the one with the most movies; you need to use `COUNT` 3. Directors don't produce movies; they direct them... but I guess that's just nitpicking

Comment: This fixed my brain error, thanks it works now:

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a logical condition in the HAVING clause, like 
HAVING MAX(MD.movie_id) > 100

Comment: I need to get the director who produced the most movies, so i need to get the 1 row with the highest grouped movie_id, do you know what i need to change then?

Comment: One way would be something like:
SELECT TOP 1 
P.lastname, P.firstname, COUNT(MD.movie_id) as MovieCount
FROM Person AS P
inner join Movie_Directors AS MD ON P.person_id=MD.person_id
inner join Movie AS M ON M.movie_id=MD.movie_id
GROUP BY P.firstname, P.lastname
ORDER BY MovieCount

Answer (score 0):

The ROW_NUMBER clause can help you.  Hopefully I don't have any typos in this.  Also, if you have a person_id, I recommend you use that instead of the firstname, lastname for the partition.

```
WITH MaxMovies AS  
(
SELECT P.lastname, P.firstname, ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY firstname, lastname ORDER BY movie_id DESC) MOVIE_NUMBER
FROM Person AS P
inner join Movie_Directors AS MD ON P.person_id=MD.person_id
inner join Movie AS M ON M.movie_id=MD.movie_id
GROUP BY P.firstname, P.lastname
)
SELECT * FROM MAXMOVIES WHERE MOVIE_NUMBER=1
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017